# Keep file observer running in background even if the app is closed

Tags: java, android, service, broadcast

I have created a file observer object and it is working fine. But my requirement is to keep the file observer alive even if the app is closed manually by the user. I could have used service to keep it running but after android O that thing is not allowed anymore. Now you may say use job scheduler but I want fileObserver to fire the event as soon as the file/folder is updated.
is there any way to do so?
thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you could use WorkManager because in theory works even the app was closed and is possible to launch the work from a reboot receiver too.

Answer (score 1):

currently you have only one option for doing this - use [ForegroundService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). its working just like usual `Service`, but it have to keep sticky `Notification`, which informs user that your app is working in background. as far as I know there is no listener firing when any folder content change...

you can also fire your code from time to time with `AlarmManager` or `WorkManager`, but still it may have some delay, may not fire in exact time and/or may drain battery (system will punish your app, flag as "battery drainer" and suggest user to force stop/uninstall, you can also get banned in GP Store)

Comment: will the foreGroundService run continuously even if i manually kill the app

Comment: yes, it may "stay alive" even when user remove app from recents